# Issue with connecting to SharePoint using PowerShell

Tags: sharepoint-online, sharepoint-foundation, powershell, modern-experience, pnp-powershell

I am trying to connect to SharePoint with the below PowerShell code. And for my account Multi-Factor Authentication is enabled.

```
$AdminSiteURL= "https://xxxxxxxxx"
Connect-PnPOnline -Url $AdminSiteURL -UseWebLogin
```

After running the code, web login window is prompting but its auto closing soon after 2 seconds. Unable to figure put the error.

Please help me with this issue.

Comment: Get-PnPList : Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://xxxxxxxxxx.
At C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Admin1.ps1:4 char:1
+ Get-PnPList
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPList], ClientRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.GetList

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried the below? It worked for me (multi-factor authentication)

```
Connect-PnPOnline -Url https://contoso.sharepoint.com -SPOManagementShell
```

More info at [MS site](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/sharepoint-pnp/connect-pnponline?view=sharepoint-ps)

Comment: ...Thanks alot for the help. Connect-PnPOnline : A parameter cannot be found that matches parameter name 'SPOManagementShell'.
getting above error after running above line. Please help me with the issue

Comment: You need to install SPO ManagementShell found at: https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=35588

Comment: I have already installed SPO Management shell but I the PnP powershell is not detecting -SPOManagementShell. Please help me if have to install anything else.

Comment: No, I've not installed anything else. If your "SharePoint Online Management" was installed correctly, you should be able to get to it from Windows run command. Are you able to do that?

Comment: I guess, you **Import-Module -Name SharePointPnPPowerShellOnline -Verbose** imported the module first, right?

Answer (score 0):

A few things to check:

1. Do you see any error message after the login window automatically close? If not, try executing a PnP command (e.g. `Get-PnPList`) and see if it returns any result or error.

   If you have previous signed in before executing the command, it might skip the authentication and log you in directly.
2. Login to the site using browser and make sure the multi-factor authentication is functioning for your account.
3. Clear the browser cache and then run the command again.

Comment: Thank you very much for the suggestion. I tried runnig the code by making the changes you mentioned. But I am getting the below error. Get-PnPList : Cannot contact site at the specified URL https://xxxxxxxxxx.
At C:\Users\xxxxx\Documents\Admin1.ps1:4 char:1
+ Get-PnPList
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : WriteError: (:) [Get-PnPList], ClientRequestException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : EXCEPTION,PnP.PowerShell.Commands.Lists.GetList.            Please help me in solving the error

Comment: I am able to get the list of titles available in the site. Hope I connected to the sharepoint site                                                                        Title                  Id                                   Url                          
-----                  --                                   ---                          
Announcements          0fa5ac45-ce41-46fc-ae81-8cb3a45c4d29 /Lists/Announcements         
appdata                dc3d4ede-9484-4038-91cf-dd73c66c83eb /_catalogs/appdata           
please suggest me if I am going wrong. Thankyou

Comment: @ChimataSrilakshmi What permission do you have in this site? Do you have trouble login into the site in web browser? Also what if you change it to another site URL?